# Why doesn't my compass point to my bed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My compass *was* working. It was pointing to my bed when I went off exploring, and the compass seemed to work.  However, when I tried to go home it just took me to a random spot on the map, and now I'm lost.

How can I fix this and find my way home?

Comment: Which game are you talking about?  Minecraft?

Comment: Yea minecraft sorry I forgot to add that :-o

Answer (score 6):

A compass does not point to your bed, so this cannot be fixed.  It points towards the initial spawn point of your world.